# ApexPages Namespace -Prefixing discrepancy

Tags: namespace

Component, Message classes belong to ApexPages namespace, but for some reason the below is possible(without namespace prefix on the Component class). The below line does NOT compile if prefixed with namespace,i.e.`ApexPages.Component.Apex.PageBlock` is not compilable.

```
Component.Apex.PageBlock pageBlk = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
```

where as Message class mandates(does not compile without the namespace) the namespace usage(ApexPages)

```
ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity, summary);
```

Has anybody experienced the same?